# I want to add non database field in a form in ORACLE APEX

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a  department table and it contains Employee information what I need is to add text fields(non-database) and performs calculation tasks using stored procedures. Can anyone help me at this [I want to add text fields here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ194.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a non-database item. [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/bldr_pg_comp.htm#HTMDB25138)

> To create a computation to store the combined values of P10_AREA_CODE,
>   P10_PREFIX, and P10_LINE_NUMBER in new items:
>
> Navigate to the appropriate Page Definition.
>
> Create an item named P10_PHONE_NUMBER to store the combined values of P10_AREA_CODE, P10_PREFIX, and P10_LINE_NUMBER.
>
> Access the Create Computation Wizard:
>
> Tree view - Under the appropriate event, locate Computations. Right-click and select Create.
>
> Component view - Under Computations, click the Create icon.
>
> For Item Location, select Item on this Page and click Next.
>
> For Computation, select P10_PHONE_NUMBER.
>
> For Sequence, select the order of evaluation.
>
> For Computation, you can create the following computation types:

**Static Assignment:**

> For Computation Type, select Static Assignment and click Next.
>
> Enter the following computation:
>
> ```
>  &P10_AREA_CODE.) &P10_PREFIX.-&P10_LINE_NUMBER.
> ```
>
> Click Next.

**PL/SQL Function Body:**

> For Computation Type, select PL/SQL Function Body and click Next.
>
> Enter the following computation:
>
> ```
> DECLARE
> l_return_value  VARCHAR2(300) DEFAULT NULL;
> BEGIN
>     l_return_value :=
> '('||:P10_AREA_CODE||')'||:P10_PREFIX||'-'||:P10_LINE_NUMBER;
> RETURN l_return_value;
> END;
> ```
>
> Click Next.

**SQL Query (return colon separated value):**

> For Computation Type, select SQL Query (return colon separated value) and click Next.
>
> Enter the following computation:
>
> ```
> SELECT '('||:P10_AREA_CODE||')'||:P10_PREFIX||'-'||:P10_LINE_NUMBER FROM DUAL
> ```
>
> Click Next.

**PLSQL Expression:**

> For Computation Type, select PLSQL Expression and click Next.
>
> Enter the following computation:
>
> `'('||:P10_AREA_CODE||')'||:P10_PREFIX||'-'||:P10_LINE_NUMBER`
>
> Click Next.
>
> Click Create.